# How to clear a Cosmos (MongoAPI) collection using Azure CLI command?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to clear all my data before new data upload on regular interval. So I need to clear the data only. I don't want to delete and recreate my collections for the same.

Comment: For CLI command, [official doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/mongodb?view=azure-cli-latest) doesn't provide sample for 'deleteAll', it only provides collection delete and create as you said in the question. Then I tried to find a useful rest api, but also failed, only found [delete one document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/delete-a-document). I only found mongodb shell script for [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/). I think you may have no other options to use delete collection via CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to delete all documents in a collection, in a single operation. You would either need to do this on your own via whatever method you want, for enumerating and deleting documents. Alternatively, you can drop and re-add a collection, which should be significantly more efficient than deleting documents individually, and won't have an RU-based throttle.

One other alternative approach: Configure TTL on your documents. With a bit of creativity here, you could target the TTL on each of your added documents to expire around the same time, effectively resulting in an automatic document-deletion mechanism.